How to use Build Phases to resolve *.swiftinterface error: 'RealmSwiftObject' is not a member type of struct 'RealmSwift.Realm'
I need to merge the ObjectMapper and RealmSwift libraries with some transform functions.
When compiling, the swiftinterface file will report the following error:
'RealmSwiftObject' is not a member type of struct 'RealmSwift.Realm'
'RealmSwiftEmbeddedObject' is not a member type of struct 'RealmSwift.Realm'

this is source code:
https://github.com/tospery/ObjectMapper-Realm-Hi
So, I want to add scripts to Build Phases to modify errors:
1、"Realm.RealmSwiftObject" change to "RealmSwift.Object"
2、"Realm.RealmSwiftEmbeddedObject" change to "RealmSwift.EmbeddedObject"
The script is:
#!/bin/bash

# Define the search and replace strings
SEARCH_STRING1="Realm.RealmSwiftObject"
REPLACE_STRING1="RealmSwift.Object"

SEARCH_STRING2="Realm.RealmSwiftEmbeddedObject"
REPLACE_STRING2="RealmSwift.EmbeddedObject"

# Find all .swiftinterface files in the build directory
SWIFT_INTERFACE_FILES=$(find "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR" -name '*.swiftinterface')

# Perform the search and replace in each .swiftinterface file
for file in $SWIFT_INTERFACE_FILES; do
    sed -i '' "s/$SEARCH_STRING1/$REPLACE_STRING1/g" "$file"
    sed -i '' "s/$SEARCH_STRING2/$REPLACE_STRING2/g" "$file"
done

But, it's not working.
Which master, can help me to adjust this script, make it work?
